# Trailing \n when i use fgetc

Tags: c, file, io

I wrote a simple function  to read a text document and prrint it as it is.But i see some trailing \n in the output.I am not able to figure out the reason.

```
void read_file(FILE* fp , char* s)
{
  int i=0;
  char c;
  while( (c=fgetc(fp)) !=EOF )
  {
    s[i]=c;
    //fseek(fp,1,SEEK_CUR);
    i++;
  }
  printf("%d is length of file\n",i);
  s[i]='\0';

  printf("%s",s);
}
```

My text document contains

> I am
>
> here

Comment: You do not want to include a newline?

Answer (score 0):

First: You need to declare `c` as `int`. The return value of `fgetc` is `int`, because `char` is usually not large enough to hold `EOF`.

The reason for getting trailing newlines i the output is either because of `c` not being an `int` or because your input file contains trailing newlines.

Comment: How could `c` not being an `int` account for it?

Comment: Because the behaviour would be undefined and I wanted to hedge my answer. The actual outcome would probably be that it either stops reading from the file if it contains a byte with the value -1, or that it writes a whole bunch of bytes with value 255 until it runs out of disk space.

Comment: I just want to know why it is an undefined behaviour. If the `char` type is implemented as `signed char`, then `c` can hold the value of `EOF`. If `char` type is implemented as `unsigned char`, then it would be an unsigned integer overflow which is defined behaviour. Is it because in the latter case, the value of `c` won't represent any character in the machine character set?

Comment: I think you are assuming that EOF == -1. The standard makes no such requirement. If EOF is defined as 9999 and chars are 8 bits, then EOF cannot be stored in a char.

Comment: I read in an answer on SO that the value of `EOF` is essentially negative. However, I don't know if it is mandated by the standard.

Comment: It must be a value that isn't equal to any valid char. Other than that, any int value can be used.

Comment: I changed c to int but still getting trailing \n and i am sure there are no \n in the text file

Comment: What file size does the program print and what file size (in bytes) does the OS report?